# Write type property in a PDF or XML file

Tags: xml, pdf, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have a model defined as:

```
<types>                                                                     
      <type name="my:firstTask">                                                
        <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>                                          
        <properties>                                                            

          <property name="my:nameAnswer">                                       
            <title>What is your name ? </title>                                 
            <type>d:text</type>                                                 
          </property>                                                           
          <property name="my:olderThanThirtyAnswer">                            
            <title>Are you older than thirty ?</title>                          
            <type>d:boolean</type>                                              
          </property>                                                           
          <property name="my:commentAnswer">                                    
            <title>Please leave a comment below</title>                         
            <type>d:text</type>                                                 
          </property>                                                           
        </properties>                                                           
      </type>
```

There are the fields of a review task in the workflow.

I need to export the answers of this fields to a PDF or to a XML at the end of the review, but I don't know how can I access these fields directly with javascript for example, and export to a PDF or to a XML. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he type which have have created is workflow task type.This properties will be associated with task of workflow.If you want to attach this properties to document, than you can write inside task complete event of workflow.Here you will have access to all JavaScript API. Using that you can do it.

See the properties section in below page , you will get more idea.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/API-JS-ScriptNode.html

Comment: Which property can I use for this? I don't know how can I access the value of d:text for example.

Comment: I have an example more or less equal, with person.properties.info ... but is an aspect... In this case I don't know, I need an example

Comment: Please take a look on properties section of provided link.

Comment: Ok , but I need to register the file that has the type in bootstrap as the person ? I can't access the property

Comment: It doesn't find the "node" that I replace with starttask. A need to know what is wrong

Comment: node is a document in alfresco.You can access it in event using bpm_package variable. bpm_package.children[0] will return first document attached.bpm_package is an array of document.